# Updating Index Value in For Loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing

Based on an element found in a list, I'd like to update the index value in my for loop.  I believe I've done this, but my Python script doesn't seem to be outputting the correct values and I cannot figure out why:

My list looks like this:

```
dataXY = [['6', 'c', '3', '7', '2', '9', '1', '7'],['8', '4', 'c', '7', '9', '3', '4', '7', '1', '2']]
```

And my code that works on this is:

```
for lists in dataXY:
    XYbezier = []
    final_lists = []
    for datum in range(len(lists)):
        if lists[datum] == 'c':
            for k in range(-1,4):
                if k != 0:
                    XYbezier.append(lists[datum+k])
        else:
            if lists[datum-1] == 'c':
                datum += 3
                if datum != len(lists):
                    final_lists.append(lists[datum])
            else:   
                final_lists.append(lists[datum])
    print datum
```

What it's printing is this:
1
5
3
4
5
6
7
0
1
2
6
4
5
6
7
8
9

For some reason, the index value is being reset, but then restored (from how it skips to 5 from 1 and then goes back to 3)  I don't understand why it's doing this, and I need the index value to jump 3 places and permanently update instead of restoring itself back to its original value.

Comment: In plain English - what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a for loop, the index variable is loaded from values in a list.
`range(x)` creates the list `[0,1,2, ... ,x]` so on each iteration, `datum` (in your case) gets a new numerical value off that list. This overrides any value that `datum` may hold.

You can accomplish your goal by switching to a `while` loop:

```
datum = 0
end = len(lists)
while datum < end:
    # do stuff

    # don't forget to increment datum
    datum += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop:

```
datum=0
while datum < len(lists):
```

In a for-loop the value of `datum` will be automatically reset to the next value from the `range` as soon as the loop begins again. Though a `while` loop will not update `datum` automatically  like for-loop does, you'll have to increase it yourself, otherwise your code will stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Does that syntax… work? And could you explain why what the OP tried didn’t?

Comment: Now shouldn’t it be `while datum < len(lists)`?